# The authorization of the Artifactory in Jenkins does not work

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, jenkins, artifactory

I´m using Artifactory 2.4.0 and Jenkins 1.438 and I have maven project with several modules. Need to deploy all modules(jars and one resulting war)
into remote Artifactory server by Jenkins.

My user admin for artifactory was with default password (password) and all builds that I tried to execute on jenkins works fine.  So when I resolved
to change de Artifactory admin password and update my settings with the new credentials of admin, I had the following error on jenkins build log:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project pilotoExemplo: Failed to deploy artifacts: 
Could not transfer artifact br.com.pilotoExemplo:pilotoExemplo:pom:2.1.0.11-20120705.160113-1 from/to snapshot 
({ip_server}/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local): Failed to transfer file: 
{ip_server}/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/br/com/pilotoExemplo/pilotoExemplo/2.1.0.11-SNAPSHOT/pilotoExemplo-2.1.0.11-20120705.160113-1.pom. 
Return code is: 401
```

Anyone already saw this problem before? I don´t found anything like this search on the google.

Here is my settings.xml:

```
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>repositorio</name>
      <url>{ip_server}/artifactory/repo</url>
      <id>repositorio</id>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
 
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>{ip_server}/artifactory/libs-release/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>{ip_server}/artifactory/libs-snapshot/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release</name>
          <url>{ip_server}/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
      <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>release</id>
        <url>{ip_server}/artifactory/libs-release-local/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshot</id>
        <url>{ip_server}/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
      </distributionManagement>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
 
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
 
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>snapshot</id>
       <username>admin</username>
      <password>newPassword</password>
    </server>
 
    <server>
      <id>release</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>newPassword</password>
    </server>
 
    <server>
      <id>repositorio</id>
       <username>admin</username>
      <password>newPassword</password>
    </server>
 
  </servers>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Jenkins jobs can have their own M2 repository, or they use the repository of the user. So the answer could be, that **your jenkins is running as a service** (maybe as local system account), and **not in the name of your user**.

You can check the user name at the Jenkins setting/system information page (yourcontextroot/systemInfo). So basicly the solution is to put the same settings file for the running user, like you have.

Comment: I checked the systeminfo page of my Jenkins and I found the variable: "user.name" defined like "tomcat". My jenkins has user and group defined as "tomcat". But I did not understand what you mean with: "put the same settings file for the running user, like you have"

Could you explain better?

Thank you for help me!

Comment: It means, that you have a tomcat user, which has a home with a m2 directory. And it has to have an m2 settings file (like you also have one for your own user), which defines the artifactory authentication for maven, if its running in the name "tomcat".

Answer (score 1):

Tip to solve the problem with the clear text password:

- Access and login into Artifactory.
- Once you are logged in, click over your user name, on the superior right corner of the screen.
- Put your password then clique in the em Unlockbutton, enabling the encrypted password.
- Copy the tag that will be showed on the inferior part of the screen and paste it into the settings.xml file. If you prefer to just copy the password, be sure about let it exactly equals the tag showed below, including the "\" at the beginning of the password.
- Remember to adjust the tag with the id of your server, defined into the tag, in your POM.xml
- Click in Update button and ready! Check if everything will occur well at the next project's publication.

Comment: this is not a full, self-contained answer. bare links should be posted in comments to the original question. this is due to the fact that linked pages tend to move, change or become outdated. you should extract and quote here fragments of the linked page that resolve the issue for the answer to be complete.